# DDD vs Clean Code - function parameter number

Tags: java, coding-style, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to get my coding a little more into DDD aproach. Suppose I have a method, like a static constructor:

```
public class Enrollment {
    private final User user;
    private final EnrollmentStatus status;
    private final ClassesParams classesParams;

    public static Enrollment of(User user, EnrollmentStatus status, ClassesParams classesParams) {
        // implementation goes here
    }
}
```

Robert Martin says in his Clean Code book, that the less parameters function has the better, and 3 should be used in some exceptional cases. And I think it's perfectly reasonable in the above case to have just 1 parameter, because all these arguments are actually parts of some input data to create new `Enrollment`:

```
public static Enrollment of(NewEnrollmentRequest request) { // NewEnrollmentRequest would contain user, status and classesParams
    // implementation goes here
}
```

The problem now is that `NewEnrollmentRequest` would be in fact some form of DTO, which is not part of the domain. And I guess I'm not supposed to put `NewEnrollmentRequest` outside the domain, because domain shouldn't depend on outside layers.

So the question is, how can I keep it both clean and DDD-style? Is it fine to have the constructor with all the fields - but what if I have not 3 but 6-7 fields? Or maybe the request class is part of the domain in this case? I feel there is some sort of tradeoff here, but I can't find it, or I'm just tackling the problem wrongly.

Comment: This feels like a classic case of you serving the architecture, instead of the architecture serving you.

Comment: Minor quibble: Your `of` method is a static *factory* method, not a *constructor*.

Comment: @RobertHarvey what do you mean?

Comment: As a simple example of what I mean: if you need DTO's, but there's some rule in your architecture that forbids you from using them, then your architecture is not serving you well. Your focus as a software developer should be on meeting customer requirements, not slavishly following some architecture's rules.

Comment: what does ClassisParams contain?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't want to follow the architecture rules blindly, that's why I started this topic to understand this problem properly. It's a common case that a domain object with many (>3) fields needs to be created. And I'd like to know how to handle such case to keep the code clean and not to mix everything with everything. And the "DTO is not part of the domain" rule also must have come for some reason. I'd like to understand, when this rule applies, when it doesn't apply etc. "Don't be a slave of your architecture" doesn't really clarify anything.

Comment: @Renato it contains a couple of fields: classesLocation, classesType.

Comment: However, I think you can use the status in a different manner: for example if you had methods like `create` and `delete`, you would avoid to pass the status from outside and set it to `created` and `deleted` directly  inside the methods. What do you think about?

Comment: The status is ACTIVE/INACTIVE enum, I can create an active or inactive Enrollment. That's not the point, there might be another field in Enrollment like ScheduleParams or anything that's some data to be set during Enrollment creation.

Comment: I think that's the point instead. I'm talking about responsability: if you have a class that actually does nothing but create an object with all parameters decided outside of it, probabily that class is not well designed ... but that's just my two cents!

Comment: And at last: I think that this is the meaning of the rule you mentioned, not just an arbitrary limit to the number of parameters: why 3 and not 4?, but a direction, an alarm bell: "if this class needs too many information, probabily I missed something at design level"

Comment: 1. I never said the class "does nothing but create an object", I just included the part of the code that I'm concerned about. I also might have methods to activate/deactivate or any other method inside the Enrollment that's doing some business logic.
2. What's the problem wih class that its fields are created outside of it? It's like creating an `OrderEntry` object with `product` field - usually you don't construct the `Product` object inside `OrderEntry`, you get it from outside and just set as part of entry. Is this also wrong?

Comment: My point is, don't get too attached to the example I posted. It might be anything, like `Order` - it usually has lots of fields like order entries, customer, payment method, delivery method etc. And I guess you don't complain that it needs too much information, you still want to create it with all these fields. My question is, again, how do you handle this to keep it clean in the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247344/discussion-between-xkrasusx-and-renato).

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is, how can I keep it both clean and DDD-style?

- Create your domain interfaces in a way that conforms to the clean style
- Including value objects with fluent interfaces that make clear to the programmer the semantics of the information that is being passed to the domain model.  (In other words, having representations of *documents*, like an enrollment form, in your domain model is *normal*).
- expect that you'll need to have a [parser](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/) that copies information from the representations of the presentation layer to the representations of the domain model.  *Sometimes* you will be able to leverage general purpose code that copies information from one information to another (like web server libraries that translate application/x-www-form-urlencoded byte sequences into sequences of key value pairs, or takes an application/json byte sequence and initializes your value object), but you should recognize that as a [happy accident](https://einarwh.wordpress.com/2020/05/08/on-the-complexity-of-json-serialization/) that may not hold for the life of the project.

Don't sweat the argument *count* constraint too much - [Robert Martin's 2009 essay](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1375308) doesn't support his conclusion very well.

Instead, pay attention to the communication of argument semantics, and the fact that the arguments (a) have different lifespans and (b) those lifespans tend to "clump" into groups that are candidates for re-use.